# Google sheets group script error when only 1 line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that copies the data from one sheet into another which acts as an archive. I have it so when it pastes the data into the archive sheet, it will group and collapse the data. However, when it is only 1 row I don't want it to group the data. This is causing an error:

> "Exception. Invalid argument"

which is in reference to this line:

```
ts.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
```

I think a solution to this might be to incorporate an if array where if the range of data copied has 1 row do nothing, 2 rows will offset by 1 row then group then collapse, and 3 or more rows will run the same code I have below.

Here is the code that selects the data, groups, and then collapse it:

```
 ts.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
 ts.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate(); //offset by 1 row for the header
 var currentCell = ts.getCurrentCell();
 ts.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
 currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
 ts.getActiveRange().shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();
```

**Full script:**

```
function CopyRangeSoldTest() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vT4R-_xPx3Z7bOYWgpOp2JCypL2yODxcJ'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sold'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getDataRange(); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1srDDle9R81Qlh'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sold History'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+2,1,ss.getLastRow(),5).setValues(data)
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(),1,ts.getLastRow(),5).activate();
 ts.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
 ts.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
 var currentCell = ts.getCurrentCell();
 ts.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
 currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
 ts.getActiveRange().shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();//.shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();//you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange() 
 
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vT4R-_xPx3Z7bOYWgpOp2JCypL2yODx'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Received'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getDataRange(); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1srDDle9R81Qlh'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Received History'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+2,1,ss.getLastRow(),5).setValues(data)
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow(),1,ts.getLastRow(),5).activate();
 ts.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
 ts.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
 var currentCell = ts.getCurrentCell();
 ts.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
 currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
 ts.getActiveRange().shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();//.shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();//you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange() 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

I understand you recorded a Macro to generate this code. However, if you do some research on the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) you will be able to write your own code and achieve the same result in way less lines but also generalize it so it could work for multiple projects.

However, a direct solution to your problem might be the following:

You can get the values of the `selection` and check if the length of this array is larger than `1` or in other words, the selected data contains more than `1` rows:

`var nrows = ts.getSelection().getActiveRange().getValues().length;`

and then use an `if` condition to check whether the data contains more than `1` row: `if(nrows>1)`.

**Solution:**

Try this:

```
 ts.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
 ts.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate(); //offset by 1 row for the header
 var currentCell = ts.getCurrentCell();
 var nrows = ts.getSelection().getActiveRange().getValues().length;
 if (nrows>1){
 ts.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
 currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
 ts.getActiveRange().shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! However, when I tried to input into my current code, it seems that even though I have more than 1 row, it doesn't collapse. I attempted to troubleshoot this by adding Logger.log(nrows); to check and it returns 1 every time despite having multiple rows. Any thoughts on what might be causing this?